# How to find a cyclical python script on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, server, cron

I have a problem with the python script on the Ubuntu server. Scripts are performed every night. How can I find them? I mean their location.
Crontab - empty
crontab.d, .daily, .weekly - empty
init.d - empty
I have root access

Comment: By "cyclical" I imagine you mean "periodically executing"? If indeed it is a cron job, the cron logs should reveal when and why; but there are other ways to make things run repeatedly, like `at` or an endless loop with a sleep or alarm. Anyway, this is system administration, not programming, so off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: In my opinion, programming ... A script has been written and set to run automatically. I'm just asking where it could have been set ...

Comment: How did you find out that a script is executed automatically? This may give you some hints for searching like the name of the script, the PID, maybe the parent's PID etc.

Comment: check also `/var/spool/cron` for other users crons

Comment: Tak / var / spool / cron !!!
It is here that the root file contains references to scripts and, consequently, to their location. 
Thank You @RomeoNinov

Comment: @k_turek, added as answer. Feel free to upvite or/ans accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the cron files of users, which are located in `/var/spool/cron` The files are named like usernames. You can also use command like

```
crontab -l -u username
```

to list the cron for particular user